# How to completely disable updates of all kinds, and not ever see prompts to update?

Tags: 12.04, updates, update-manager

I'm shipping a ubuntu-based system which once shipped will never be connected to a network. I never, ever, ever want it to prompt the user to check for updates, and I never ever ever want it to try to check for updates.

I definitely never want the red triangle with exclamation mark to appear in the Gnome menu bar.

I have already done this:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic 
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
```

And this:

```
$ dconf write /apps/update-manager/remind-reload false
$ gconftool -s --type bool /apps/update-notifier/auto_launch false
```

And this:

```
$ cat /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
Prompt=never
```

But even with all that, it *still* periodically shows the red triangle with ! saying it failed to check for updates.

What have I missed?

Comment: While the Update Manager isn't very useful for a totally non-networked system, *such a system may still be vulnerable.* Suppose your OS has an app that opens files of some type brought in from the outside. Apps can be vulnerable to specially crafted data files (e.g., *a picture*), that can cause execution of arbitrary code. ([This happened to MS Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/833987); it could happen on Ubuntu.) So you should (1) find a way to provide updates, or (2) make the system so minimal you can track vulnerabilities yourself. Way 2's probably impossible on *any* Ubuntu desktop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to **System Settings** > **Software & Updates** or type `software-properties-gtk` in a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal), and select Updates tab. That window it should look like in next image if you want to not recieve any kind of updates:

[image]

Or, from terminal, comment (with `#` at the start of every line) all the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

To automatically comment everything in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, use:

```
cd /etc/apt && sudo cp sources.list sources.list.bak && sudo sed -i -e 's/^/#/g' sources.list
```

This command create also a backup for `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and can be very useful when you have to configure many computers.

Comment: There is no "Software & Updates" icon in System Settings. How can I enable that? (As I noted in my tags, I'm on 12.04 LTS.)

Comment: Also, is there a way to do this from the command line? Where is this getting its data? I need to make this part of my system configuration script.

Comment: @dmd If you use Unity, just search in Dash for *Software & Updates*.

Comment: I can get this window up using software-properties-gtk, and indeed some of those are checked. What does their being checked correspond to in the apt system? How can I disable this in a file/from command line?

Comment: @dmd Why do you need to do this from command-line when you can simply view what exactly you are doing using GUI.

Comment: Because I'm building hundreds of systems and need to do this on all of them.

Comment: Anyway, I see now that this just modifies sources.list. I can change that.

Comment: @dmd From terminal you can comment all the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` file

Comment: @dmd For many systems you can use `sudo sed -i -e 's/^/#/g' sources.list`

Comment: Hey guys, put all the goodies in the answer, not buried in the comments!